# NSXMLParser throws NSXMLParserErrorDomain #64 on <?xml version="1.0"?>

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

A NSXMLParserErrorDomain #64 is thrown by NSXMLParser if it finds the following line:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Makes no difference if I initWithContentsOfUrl or initWithData.  The xml is coming via a php5.3 apache system.  If this line is omitted the document parses without error.  We own the server so I can filter this line out, but I'd rather fix the parser.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that this error is an `NSXMLParserMisplacedXMLDeclarationError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there's not some cruft on the line, like a byte order mark or other hidden characters? It's the only thing I could think of that would cause an error on that line, assuming of course this is the first line in the document?

Also, adding `encoding="UTF-8"` might help, but again, it must be the very first line of the document, and watch for hidden characters, mistyped spaces (nbsp-s instead of spaces, etc.), and so on.

Comment: Ur right...The Junk Values coming before the <xml...> tag is the reason for the errors..U can try out the solution suggested below by DejanR. It works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is happened because PHP server return some junk and empty spaces before `<?XML` heading.
Here is simple solution that work for me, just correct the incoming string before the parse:

```
NSRange range = [theXML rangeOfString:@"<?xml"];
theXML = [[theXML substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(range)-5] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSData *xmldata = [theXML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
```